# Is Firebase Cloud Messaging suitable for messaging apps?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

We're writing an app like LINE, and need notification service for each single message in a chat group when app is in background.
We try to use Firebase Cloud Messaging for this feature, but I can't see a reasonable implementation.

Topic subscribing is too slow for "create a topic for each chat group" since it takes hours to create one. Device group messaging is designed for devices owned by a single user. Using sending to a single device feature for each receiver and each message does not seem to be practical since the server loading is too heavy.

Is there a good way to use FCM making such app, or do I need to find another service? Thanks.

Comment: By *Multiple Devices*, do you mean [Device Group Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group)?

Comment: Yes I do. As it says `"group" refers a set of different devices that belong to a single user.`

Comment: I see. Device Group Messaging isn't technically designed for just a single user with multiple devices. It is ***typically*** used for that use-case, but can also be used depending on your need.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a try.